# How to pass a list variable to another CMake call?

Tags: cmake

In my CMake scripts, I run other CMake instances using `exec_program(${CMAKE_COMMAND} ...)`. I want to make the `${CMAKE_MODULES_PATH}` of the parent environment available to the child environments. Therefore, I tried to pass the variable as argument:

```
exec_program(${CMAKE_COMMAND} ... ARGS ...
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ...)
```

This messes up the other parameters and I get a `CMake Error: The source directory <first-module-path> does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`. Therefore, I tried escaping the variable:

```
exec_program(${CMAKE_COMMAND} ... ARGS ...
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}" ...)
```

When I print the `${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}` form within the child environment, all the paths get printed, separated by a space each. However, CMake doesn't find scripts inside those paths. I guess it has something to do with the list being passed as string rather than a semi-color separated list.

How can I pass a CMake variable holding a list of strings to another CMake command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my CMake scripts, I run other CMake instances using exec_program(${CMAKE_COMMAND} ...)

According to [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/exec_program.html) this command is deprecated:

```
Deprecated. Use the execute_process() command instead.
```

Example with the list variable, CMakeLists.txt:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" "-DVAR=A;B;C" -P script.cmake
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE output
)
```

script.cmake:

```
message("VAR: ${VAR}")

foreach(x ${VAR})
  message("x: ${x}")
endforeach()
```

output:

```
VAR: A;B;C
x: A
x: B
x: C
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out as well. But what if instead of some hard coded items, I want to pass a list that is stored in a variable?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Seems like the newer `execute_process()` handles things a bit better.