# CMake and execute_process

Tags: cmake

Having a little trouble with cmake.  I'm working in a weird mode where I need cmake to call an external cmake script to execute multiple commands as part of a test.  I've boiled it down to this example.

```
test.cmake:
message("CMD: " ${CMD})
message("ARG: " ${ARG})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMD} ${ARG}
           RESULT_VARIABLE result
           OUTPUT_VARIABLE output
           )
message("RESULT: " ${result})
message("OUTPUT: " ${output})

mytest:
cmake -DCMD="cmake" -DARG="-E sleep 10" -V -P ./test.cmake 

output:
CMD: cmake
ARG: -E sleep 10
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/user/-E sleep 10" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
RESULT: 1
```

It works fine for all other CMD settings besides CMD=cmake.  Any thoughts?

Passing ARG as "-E;sleep;10" works but my higher level project looks like:

```
 project( test NONE)
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
 enable_testing()
 set(ARG "-E;sleep;-10")
 # set(ARG "-E;sleep -10")  
 # set(ARG "-E sleep -10")
 add_test( NAME test
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMD=cmake -DARG=${ARG} -P test.cmake)
```

And this fails :/

Tony

Comment: As you can see from error message, CMake treats your *ARG* variable as **single-valued** (but with spaces). You need *list-variable*. E.g. by setting it to "-E;sleep;10".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a list variable to another CMake call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633583/how-to-pass-a-list-variable-to-another-cmake-call)

Comment: Yep that worked!  Thanks!  But my more complicated issues still do not work.  I have something that looks like

Comment: Yep that worked!  Thanks!  But my more complicated issues still do not work.  I have something that looks like:`project( test NONE)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
enable_testing()
set(ARG "-E;sleep;-10")
# set(ARG "-E;sleep -10")
# set(ARG "-E sleep -10")
add_test( NAME test
          COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMD=cmake -DARG=${ARG} -P test.cmake)` And this fails....

Comment: Within *COMMAND*, enclose `-DARG=${ARG}` into double quotes.

Comment: Wow! That worked thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To address this, you would have to use a different list separator. For example: `^^` would do it.

Note that updating a list with such a separator is also easy in newer version of CMake:

```
list(JOIN ${ARGS} "^^" ARG)
```

Calling `test.cmake` would the be done using:

```
cmake -DCMD="cmake" -DARG="-E^^sleep^^1" -V -P ./test.cmake
```

and the `test.cmake` would be like this:

```
message("ARG: ${ARG}")
string(REPLACE "^^" ";" ARGS ${ARG})

message("CMD: ${CMD}")
message("ARGS:")
foreach(argument IN LISTS ARGS)
  message(STATUS "  ${argument}")
endforeach()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMD} ${ARGS}
           RESULT_VARIABLE result
           OUTPUT_VARIABLE output
           )
message("RESULT: ${result}")
message("OUTPUT: ${output}")
```

the output looks like this:

```
ARG: -E^^sleep^^1
CMD: cmake
ARGS:
--   -E
--   sleep
--   1
RESULT: 0
OUTPUT:
```